# How to update system apps in AWS device farms?

Tags: webview, selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android, aws-device-farm

We have some of our scripts not working because the Android System WebView and Chrome browser versions are 74 version. We want to have 88 version on them.

In our local emulator, we were able to update them but since AWS have unrooted devices, we don't know how to update those versions.

It would be greatly appreciated if we get any lead on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer on the AWS Device Farm team. We currently do not offer customers the capability to update the chrome browser version on the device.

For better assistance, I suggest utilizing the AWS Device Farm forums as a medium to contact the service team: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193

Andy